# filter by ether_type and by specified bytes using libpcap

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcpdump

Thanks to `pcap_filter`, I want to filter by

- `ether_type` : Protocol 0x88b5
- AND by specific bytes in the payload : "ASK", or 0x41434b

It's ethernet-level => no network layer, directly the payload.

**=> the bytes I'm looking for are on bytes 15, 16 and 17 of the Ethernet frame, right ?**

I tried this, but this doesn't work :

```
char filter_exp[] = "ether proto 0x88b5 and ether[14:3] == 0x41434b";   

if(pcap_compile(descr,&fp,filter_exp,0,PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN) == -1)
{ fprintf(stderr,"Error calling pcap_compile\n"); exit(1); }
```

My question is :

- can we mix filters on `ether_type` and bytes ?
- If no, how can I do it ? By specifying the bytes to filter in the `ether_type` too ?

Comment: We can mix the `ether_type` and the bytes, but the number of bytes must be even (2 or 4 works)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds as if you've answered your own question:

```
ether proto 0x88b5 and ether[14:2] == 0x4143 and ether[16:1] == 0x4b
```

...if, that is, you're looking for "ACK" in the first three bytes of the packet.

If you're looking for "ASK", that'd be

```
ether proto 0x88b5 and ether[14:2] == 0x4153 and ether[16:1] == 0x4b
```

But the number of bytes doesn't have to be even, it just has to be a power of 2 between 1 and 4, i.e., 1, 2, or 4, and you can have multiple tests.

Comment: Yeah, basically, that's it :)